# Reversible adiabatic process insight

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, adiabatic

How can a  reversible adiabatic process (theoretically) be brought about since the  system is insulated? A $\mathrm dP$ change in pressure will lead to a $\mathrm dT$ change in temperature thus disturbing the thermodynamic equilibrium.
Because there is a temperature difference between the system and the surrounding which isn't possible in an reversible process.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! I have tried to improve the clarity of your question. If I misunderstood your intent, please [edit] further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they say adiabatic, they mean perfectly insulated.

You can have a temperature difference between the system and the environment, but you just pretend that zero heat flows. That’s just a given. You are told to assume it.

Maybe that is not always realistic, especially when there are big temperature differences. But we assume it’s true to do the theoretical problem and learn. And sometimes is ok assumption in real life situations if close to true. But yes there is no perfect insulation. In reality, there would be heat lost through the insulation (and also **into** the insulation to set-up a temperature gradient, because the insulation is not zero mass, and is not zero “thermal mass”). Idealized case.

Comment: Basically my point is that can there be Temperature difference btw system and surrounding in a reversible process if no then how the temperature of the system will rise .how can the system be in thermodynamic equilibrium if there is temp difference btw system and surrounding

Comment: I did not understand what are u are trying to say plz explain by few egs and also plz be little bit specific as i have raised many ques

Comment: Adiabatic means no heat energy flows in or out. We might still gain or lose energy by changing the volume. If the volume of the system expands, then the system does work on the environment, and the system loses some energy that way. If it reduces in volume it gains energy. Make sense so far?

Comment: Yes ot makes sense so far but ques remains unanswered how temp of any system can rise in an reversible process if surr3temp remains constant ? Will it not hamper thermal equilibrium condition

Comment: @Bhaumik Oooh. I see. *I edited my answer!*

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t see what you are looking at. Maybe it’s not an “accept” button but there has to be a mechanism. Maybe just an up arrow

Comment: @BobD took me a minute to follow this comment haha. I thought you were talking about my answer and adiabatic mechanism

Answer (score 2):

I tried to explain this in connection with your other answer. But here's another try.

A reversible process is one in which no entropy is generated. Causes of entropy product include, but are not necessarily limited to, the following:

1. Heat transfer occurs across a finite temperature difference.

This is what is meant by thermal disequilibrium. There is no thermal disequilibrium between two objects having different temperatures if there is no opportunity for heat to transfer between the two object. Insulating the system from the surroundings in an adiabatic process prevents the opportunity of heat transfer across a finite temperature difference.

2. Work transfer involving a finite pressure difference.

For a reversible adiabatic process the difference in pressure is always infinitesimal so that the pressures can be considered the same, i.e., the system and surroundings are in mechanical equilibrium. This, plus the absence of any mechanical friction, makes the adiabatic process reversible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: It will help in my jee advanced prep thks once again

Comment: Glad it helped. So then was my answer acceptable?

Comment: i dont know how to accept an answer as a i new to tyhis platform,

Comment: Next to each answer you should see an “accept” button

Comment: There is no such option

Comment: On my screen, there is a grey check mark ✔️ below the up arrow.  Also you should be upvoting if someone helps you. I will upvote Bob’s answer.